# TF400324: The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I encountered this issue  after trying to get the latest version from visual studio (2012 update 2).

I tried to reconnect and even restart visual studio, but it didn't help.

> TF400324: Team Foundation services are not available from server my-project.visualstudio.com.
>   Technical information (for administrator):
>     The underlying connection was closed: The message length limit was exceeded.

Any ideas?

Comment: Same issue here.  I suggest tweeting @TFService and letting them know.

Comment: Current status:Investigating issues on unable to connect to TFS



For details and history, check out the TFS Service blog : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfservice/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same also to me and my team, hope microsoft is on the problem!

You can see the Service Status from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/support/ and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsoservice/

Service status
Investigating issues impacting users using Eclipse

For details and history, check out the TFS Service blog.

Actually is not just for Eclipse!! :|

Comment: I'm aware this was posted 3 years ago, but that link just redirects to a visual studio landing page now.

Comment: thank you for notice this, I've fixed the link

Answer (score 2):

- Now fixed. Sorry for the trouble! *

We're looking into it - there's a workaround if you can't wait:

```
del %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies /s" from an elevated command prompt
```

It should be fixed shortly...sorry for the inconvenience...

Comment: I appreciate the quick fix.